# Namespace include not working

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm working on the Opscode IIS cookbook, in my provider `iis_site` I have

```
include ::Opscode::IIS::Helper
```

in my libraries folder I have a file called helper.rb

```
#
# Cookbook Name:: iis
# Library:: helper
#
# Author:: Julian C. Dunn <jdunn@getchef.com>
#
# Copyright 2013, Chef Software, Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

module Opscode
  module IIS
    module Helper
      if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin|mingw32|windows/
        require 'chef/win32/version'
      end

      require 'rexml/document'
      include REXML

      def self.older_than_windows2008r2?
        if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin|mingw32|windows/
          win_version = Chef::ReservedNames::Win32::Version.new
          win_version.windows_server_2008? ||
          win_version.windows_vista? ||
          win_version.windows_server_2003_r2? ||
          win_version.windows_home_server? ||
          win_version.windows_server_2003? ||
          win_version.windows_xp? ||
          win_version.windows_2000?
        end
      end

      def self.is_new_value?(document, xpath, value_to_check)
        return XPath.first(document, xpath).to_s == value_to_check ? false : true
      end

      def self.is_new_or_empty_value?(document, xpath, value_to_check)
        return is_new_value(document, xpath, value_to_check) || value_to_check == '' ? false : true
      end

      def self.appcmd(node)
        return "#{node['iis']['home']}/appcmd.exe"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In the `iis_site.rb` file i'm getting the following error:

> FATAL: NoMethodError: iis_site[Default Web Site] (iis::remove_default_site line 21) had an error: NoMethodError: No resource or method named `appcmd' for`Chef::Provider::IisSite ""'

If I change the provider line from:

```
cmd = "#{appcmd(node)} add site /name:\"#{@new_resource.site_name}\""
```

to

```
cmd = "#{Opscode::IIS::Helper.appcmd(node)} add site /name:\"#{@new_resource.site_name}\""
```

the issue is resolved, however this adds a lot of repetition that shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Pretty please don't do this. You are taking generically-named functions and dumping them into the global recipe DSL. That is really asking for trouble.

Comment: @coderanger the auto include was removed. it was for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue was with using `self.`

Below is the fixed code.

```
#
# Cookbook Name:: iis
# Library:: helper
#
# Author:: Julian C. Dunn <jdunn@getchef.com>
#
# Copyright 2013, Chef Software, Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

module Opscode
  module IIS
    module Helper
      if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin|mingw32|windows/
        require 'chef/win32/version'
      end

      require 'rexml/document'
      include REXML

      def self.older_than_windows2008r2?
        if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin|mingw32|windows/
          win_version = Chef::ReservedNames::Win32::Version.new
          win_version.windows_server_2008? ||
          win_version.windows_vista? ||
          win_version.windows_server_2003_r2? ||
          win_version.windows_home_server? ||
          win_version.windows_server_2003? ||
          win_version.windows_xp? ||
          win_version.windows_2000?
        end
      end

      def is_new_value?(document, xpath, value_to_check)
        return XPath.first(document, xpath).to_s == value_to_check ? false : true
      end

      def is_new_or_empty_value?(document, xpath, value_to_check)
        return is_new_value(document, xpath, value_to_check) || value_to_check == '' ? false : true
      end

      def appcmd(node)
        @appcmd ||= begin
          "#{node['iis']['home']}\\appcmd.exe"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To complete the self-answer on the why:

Using self in the method definition means it will be an instance method only. I.e: it can be accessed only through an object of the class.

In your case you must have an object of class `::Opscode::IIS::Helper` to call `appcmd`

Your use of the full definition for the method`(This part:`"#{Opscode::IIS::Helper.appcmd(node)}`) create a temporary object on the fly to call the method

Aside of all of this, you're sending your module into the provider namespace, so you don't have to require the library at top of your provider.